# How to update range macro when cells in Excel are inserted/deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask if there is a way to update the range specified in a macro when I insert/delete cells.

For example, I have specified the range in a subroutine in my macro to be

```
Worksheets("Query Screen").Range("M22:M25") = "0"
```

Now, if I insert a new row between `M22` and `M25`, what can I do to update the range in my macro automatically to be

```
Worksheets("Query Screen").Range("M22:M26") = "0"
```

Thus, is it possible to update the macro based on changes in the Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this isn't possible.

But what you can do:

Give the range you are working on a name: e.g MyRange

After that you can use

```
Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersTo) = 0
```

That will automatically be updated after inserting rows or columns

Comment: FYI, that can be written as `ActiveWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange = 0` or `ActiveWorkbook.Range("MyRange") = 0`